# Inserted data not seen in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

I am new to InfluxDB. I am trying to insert below data to influx DB.

```
# DDL
CREATE DATABASE import

# DML
# CONTEXT-DATABASE: import

FO,type=FreshOrders avg_FreshOrders=1479.0840707964599,p95_FreshOrders=2589,FreshOrders=226 1593648000000
FO,type=FreshOrders avg_FreshOrders=2242.86170212766,p95_FreshOrders=5622,FreshOrders=188 1593475200000
FO,type=FreshOrders avg_FreshOrders=1682.3375,p95_FreshOrders=2738,FreshOrders=160 1593734400000
```

By using import option

```
./influx -import -path=/home/ec2-user/data/import.txt -precision=ns
```

I am able to insert data properly and when executed got the below output.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-19-10 bin]$ ./influx -import -path=/home/ec2-user/data/import.txt -precision=ns
2020/07/15 03:08:48 Processed 1 commands
2020/07/15 03:08:48 Processed 3 inserts
2020/07/15 03:08:48 Failed 0 inserts
```

But when i checked in the database, inserted data is not seen. Can someone please help me on this issue?

```
> use import
Using database import
> precision rfc3339
> select * from import limit 3
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have inserted data to `FO` series in `import` database, so the query should look like this:

```
select * from FO limit 3
```